# Is there a libPNG 64-Bit?

Tags: c++, windows, image, png, libpng

I have a problem with libPNG, which is leading me to believe that I need a 64bit version of libPNG to run my application on a 64bit computer. The error is `IMG_Load: Failed loading libpng15-15.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.` According to some other posts on this site, it is the fact that this is a 32bit DLL, is that the problem?

Comment: It's probably easiest just to link it statically. libPNG is small and self-contained.

Comment: If you would - please! - describe some technical details of your application you are building (compiler, OS, 32 or 64 bit, and how your application uses/links to that lib), I guess you will get much better answers.

Comment: If you compile it for 64 bit, then there'll be...

Comment: A 32-bit application needs 32-bit DLLs. A 64-bit application needs 64-bit DLLs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [libpng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libpng) works on 64-bit architectures, including x86_64.

It's an open-source library so you can compile it with your project if a precompiled binary isn't available for your platform/architecture.

Comment: I'm just using the usual libPNG runtime download, but it fails with the error above, what should I do then?

Comment: Where are you downloading it from? The [official site](http://libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) doesn't provide a windows binary.

Comment: I actually dont' know where I got it from, it works on my x86 laptop though, but not my x64 desktop computer, it's called libPNG15-15.dll

Comment: If your application is 64-bit, you're going to need a 64-bit library. Compiling it from source is likely the best option.